# Из-за чего ошибка?

Tags: python

```
def get_user(text):
    today = datetime.datetime.today()
    r = requests.get('http://gmt.star-conflict.com/pubapi/v1/userinfo.php?nickname='+text)
    i = json.loads(r.text)
    global cfg2
    if i["result"] == "ok":
        try:
            cfg2.get('id', text)
            cfg2.set('id', text+'_n', str(int(cfg2.get('id', text+'_n')))
            if cfg2.get(cfg2.get('id', text+'_n')+'_' +text, 'json') == r.text:
                cfg2.set('id', text, int(cfg2.get('id', text)+1))
                cfg2.set('id', text+'_n', int(cfg2.get('id', text+'_n')+1))
                cfg2.set(cfg2.get('id', text+'_n')+'_' +text, 'lasttime', today.strftime("%Y %m %d %H:%M:%S"))
            else:
                cfg2.set('id', text, int(cfg2.get('id', text)+1))
                cfg2.set('id', text+'_n', int(cfg2.get('id', text+'_n')+1))
                cfg2.add_section(cfg2.get('id', text)+'_'+text)
                cfg2.set(cfg2.get('id', text)+'_'+text, 'json', r.text)
                cfg2.set(cfg2.get('id', text)+'_'+text, 'time', today.strftime("%Y %m %d %H:%M:%S"))
                cfg2.set(cfg2.get('id', text)+'_'+text, 'lasttime', today.strftime("%Y %m %d %H:%M:%S"))
            with open('../users.ini', "r+") as config_file:
                cfg2.write(config_file)
        except:
            cfg2.set('id', text, '1')
            cfg2.set('id', text+'_n', '1')
            cfg2.add_section('1_'+text)
            cfg2.set('1_'+text, 'json', r.text)
            cfg2.set('1_'+text, 'time', today.strftime("%Y %m %d %H:%M:%S"))
            cfg2.set('1_'+text, 'lasttime', today.strftime("%Y %m %d %H:%M:%S"))
            with open('../users.ini', "r+") as config_file:
                cfg2.write(config_file)
    return i
```

ошибка

```
  File "main.py", line 44
    if cfg2.get(cfg2.get('id', text+'_n')+'_' +text, 'json') == r.text:
                                                                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 3):

На строку выше не хватает скобки. (((( и))). 4 открыл, 3 закрыл.